# Pip install for Python 3.0 (win XP)

Tags: python, pip

I am trying to install pip for Python 3.0  (win XP).
 I have downloaded get-pip.py, open it inside shell redactor and start as "Run module". 
 I am nor happy with Result :
 ( the same I got starting "python get-pip.py" in a command line ).
 How to solve this problem? Thanks alot

```
IDLE 3.0      
>>> ================================ RESTART ================================
>>> 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Python30\get-pip.py", line 20061, in <module>
    main()
  File "D:\Python30\get-pip.py", line 194, in main
    bootstrap(tmpdir=tmpdir)
  File "D:\Python30\get-pip.py", line 82, in bootstrap
    import pip
  File "e:\temp\tmp0azuy8\pip.zip\pip\__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
  File "e:\temp\tmp0azuy8\pip.zip\pip\_vendor\requests\__init__.py", line 62, in <module>
  File "e:\temp\tmp0azuy8\pip.zip\pip\_vendor\requests\packages\__init__.py", line 29, in <module>
ImportError: No module named urllib3
>>>
```

Comment: Python 3.0 is very old, 3.6 is the current version which has `pip` bundled in with it.  You might have better luck using the most recent version.

Answer (score 0):

From pip docs

> pip works with CPython versions 2.6, 2.7, 3.3, 3.4, 3.5 and also pypy.

Install a newer python version such as Python <=3.4.3. The latest versions >=3.5 and beyond are not compatible with Windows XP.

Comment: OK, 3.4.3 is looking OK. Thanks